# Pandas: create a random sample and correlation matrix

Tags: pandas, random, correlation

**How to create a subset of the data that contains a random sample of 200 observations (database create form a csv file)**

```
Data columns (total 10 columns):
longitude             20640 non-null float64
latitude              20640 non-null float64
housing_median_age    20640 non-null float64
total_rooms           20640 non-null float64
total_bedrooms        20433 non-null float64
population            20640 non-null float64
households            20640 non-null float64
median_income         20640 non-null float64
median_house_value    20640 non-null float64
ocean_proximity       20640 non-null object
```

**How to determine the correlations between housing values(median_house_value) and the other variables and display in descending order.**

df.corr() gives me all the correlations. How to make it show only the median house value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sample,

```
df = df.sample(200)
```

For the correlation, just do

```
df.corr()['median_house_value'].sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Comment: I believe that it is wrong to apply corr to series. You  need to use `df.corr()['median_house_value'].sort_values(ascending=False)`

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks, I should've checked taht